# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\classes\class.sql.php on line 34

Tags: mysql, php-7

I am new to `mysqli_*` and I am getting these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\classes\class.sql.php on line 34

I got the error when i change from php5 to php7 
Codes:

```
private static function select_db() {

    if ( Sql::$base != NULL )
        Sql::$db = mysqli_select_db(Sql::$base, Sql::$connect);

}
```

and this is the declaration 
code:

```
Class Sql {
  private static $host;             // Host tobeconnected
  private static $user;             // User name
  private static $password;         // Password
  private static $base;             // Database

    private static $connect;    // Connection resource
    private static $db;             // Database resource


    private function Sql() {}

    // Connects to the host
    public static function connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Base) {

        Sql::$host  = $Host;
        Sql::$user  = $User;
        Sql::$password = $Password;
        Sql::$base  = $Base;

        Sql::$connect = mysqli_connect(Sql::$host, Sql::$user, Sql::$password);
        Sql::select_db();

        return Sql::$connect;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$base`, the database name ?  It seems that you might simply have the arguments reversed. Try swapping the `$base` and `$connect` positions. As mentioned in the manual, the first argument should be the link (or connect) and the second argument is the DB name (the 'string').

Comment: `...but i still can't understand` ... which part?  Know that you can also pass the dbname as the 4th parameter to `mysqli_connect`, and there would be no need to do the `select_db` handling.  Take a moment to read the documentation on the functions at php.net, as they are explained well with example usage along with error handling when there is trouble.